# Google place api returns error on getting current location

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am working on google place API, During this I get any place from google place picker but while fetching my current location from this.

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer  likelyPlaces) {
                        Log.e("result",""+likelyPlaces);
                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                            Log.e("result", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Place "+placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName()+" has likelihood "+placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        }
                        likelyPlaces.release();
                    }
                });
```

PlaceLikelihoodBuffer returning the statusCode error:

```
PlaceLikelihoodBuffer{status=Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}, attributions=null}
```

so I am stuck here from long time, And I didn't find any solution related to this.